# Java как отследить сообщения выводящиеся на консоль

Tags: java, консоль, потоки-данных, вывод

Пытаюсь написать некий "слушатель" для отслеживания сообщений которые выводятся в консоли.
Есть класс который запускается в отдельном потоке и пишет сообщения, хотелось бы дождаться определенного сообщения типа "client registered" чтоб понять что все прошло успешно и дальше взаимодействовать по такому же принципу отслеживания сообщений в консоли. Сам класс "client" работает хорошо и переписывать/адаптировать крайне не желательно, могу использовать Thread.sleep(6000) но тоже не очень хорошее решение так как появление необходимого сообщения "client registered" может быть варьироваться от 3 до 6 секунд. Опять же есть вероятность что высветиться сообщение "client not registered" и тогда дальнейшее выполнение когда выйдет в ошибку.

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String message = "";
  boolean status;
  Client client = new Client();
  Thread myclient = new Thread(client);  
  myclient.start();
  
  // c этого момента надо ловить сообщения
  whyle (true) {
    if (message.equals("client registered") {
     status=true;
     break;
    } 

    if (message.equals("client not registered") {
     status=false;
     break;
    } 
  }
}
```

пытался использовать код по этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908485/java-how-to-mirror-console-output-to-file

```
// Feed myCaptureStream to TeeOutputStream
OutputStream myCaptureStream = new PipedOutputStream();

// Prepare to capture data being written to that output stream
InputStream myCaptureAsInputStream = new PipedInputStream(myCaptureStream);
Reader myCaptureReader = new InputStreamReader(myCaptureAsInputStream);
BufferedReader myCaptureBuffered = new BufferedReader(myCaptureReader, 1024);

// This must run on separate reader thread; in spin loop:
myCaptureBuffered.readLine
```

Здесь ошибка в строке

```
InputStream myCaptureAsInputStream = new PipedInputStream(myCaptureStream);



 Error:(31, 50) java: no suitable constructor found for 
 PipedInputStream(java.io.OutputStream)
    constructor java.io.PipedInputStream.PipedInputStream(java.io.PipedOutputStream) is not applicable
     (argument mismatch; java.io.OutputStream cannot be converted to java.io.PipedOutputStream)
   constructor java.io.PipedInputStream.PipedInputStream(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.io.OutputStream cannot be converted to int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не пойму задачу. Если сторонний класс выводит в `System.out` и это нельзя изменить (исправить), то можно использовать `System.setOut` вместе с теми же `PipedXXXStream`

Простейший пример (без обработки ресурсов, аккуратной работы с кодировками и т.п.):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PipedOutputStream pOut = new PipedOutputStream();
        PrintStream defaultOut = System.out;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(pOut));
        Thread thr = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    System.out.println("stop");
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    // interrupted
                }

            }
        };
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(pOut);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        thr.start();
        for (;;) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            defaultOut.println("Read: "+line);
            if (line.equals("stop"))
                break;
        }
        defaultOut.println("Done");
    }
```

В отдельном треде выводятся сообщения как бы в `System.out`, а в по факту перенаправляются через `PipedOutputStream`.

И не забыть потом вернуть старый `System.out`, который в этом примере в `defaultOut`.

Если же сторонний класс можно подправить, то проще и безопаснее тогда подавать ему `OutputStream` явно.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, код отлавливает сообщение прекрасно